# temporarily change fonts in latex with T1 font

Tags: latex, fonts

I want to temporarily change fonts in latex, to [arev](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/arev/). Usually, this would work, as described [here](http://xpt.sourceforge.net/techdocs/language/latex/latex32-LaTeXAndFonts/ar01s08.html):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
{\fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{arev} the font is temporarily changed}
\end{document}
```

it doesnt though, and I think it has to do with the fact that arev is a T1 font. I think I need to specify more?

Thanks in advance for any advice, I appreciate it!

Georg Raba

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
\newcommand*{\titlefont}{\fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{fav}\selectfont}
```

You need to use "fav" as the font family name. You can find this mapping by looking in arevtext.sty (for me it is in C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\arev)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
{\fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{arev}\selectfont
Arev looks like this}.
```

Comment: this works for me: 

{\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont Helvetica looks like this}
and {\fontencoding{OT1}\fontfamily{ppl} Palatino looks like this}.
}

so either you don't have the arev font package installed or you are calling the wrong font name.

Comment: {\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont Helvetica looks like this} and {\fontencoding{OT1}\fontfamily{ppl} works fine. Also, I can set arev as the default font. So the arev font package is installed and i can call it fine. The difficulty is changing it to arev temporarily. I dont know why that should be problematic, but it is..

Comment: I would guess, and it is a guess, that the font encoding has much to do with it. I change the encoding to TS1 and it out put some leaf looking characters. If you need a quick work around, why not just set arev as the sans-serif or sans or monospace font default, then you can switch into easily. this only works, of course, if you don't have anything else in the document using these declarations.